# Delphi DX 10.3 VS Delphi 6 performances

Tags: delphi, combobox, controls

I have been using **Delphi 6** for a very long time, and I recently started using version **Delphi DX Rio 10.3**.
Against all my expectations, it seems to me that **loading items on standard controls** (ComboBox, Listbox and so on) **in DX RIO is significantly slower** (at runtime) than in D6 (both in DEBUG and RELEASE mode, after activating all optimizations).
I tried using BeginUpdate / EndUpdate, without changing the speed difference between the environments.

I would like to ask if anyone has **any suggestions for improving DX 10.3 Combobox/Listbox performances**. The specific problem I'm trying to solve in my real application is to load some dozens of items in 10-20 combos/listboxes controls on my form.

I wrote a very simple test for a standard COMBO. The same program works in both D6 and DX RIO.
On my development machine (Win 10 pro) the program compiled with D6 takes about **1 second**, while the program compiled with DX RIO takes about **four times as much**.

Many thanks in advance for your answers.

```
{$A+,B-,C+,D+,E-,F-,G+,H+,I+,J-,K-,L+,M-,N+,O+,P+,Q-,R-,S-,T-,U-,V+,W-,X+,Y+,Z1}

unit Unit1;

interface

uses Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
     cb: TComboBox;
     txt_count: TLabel;
     btn: TButton;
     procedure btnClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var dt_start_timer : TDatetime;

procedure start_timer;
begin
    dt_start_timer := now
end;

function delta_timer_msec : longint;
begin
    result := round((now - dt_start_timer) * 24*60*60*1000)
end;

procedure execute(father : TForm;cb : TComboBox;txt : TLabel;bo_disable_update : boolean);
const
    MAX = 100;
    ITEMS_COUNT = 1000;
var i, j : integer;
begin
    start_timer;
    if bo_disable_update then cb.Items.BeginUpdate;
    for i := 1 to MAX do begin
        cb.Items.Clear;
        for j := 1 to ITEMS_COUNT do cb.Items.Add('text-' + intToStr(j))
    end;
    if bo_disable_update then cb.Items.EndUpdate;
    txt.Caption := intToStr(delta_timer_msec) + ' msecs'
end;

procedure TForm1.btnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    execute(self, cb, txt_count, {disable_update}TRUE)
end;

end.

object Form1: TForm1
  Left = -6
  Top = 117
  Width = 449
  Height = 350
  Caption = 'Form1'
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object txt_count: TLabel
    Left = 198
    Top = 32
    Width = 44
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'txt_count'
  end
  object cb: TComboBox
    Left = 42
    Top = 28
    Width = 145
    Height = 21
    ItemHeight = 13
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'cb'
  end
  object btn: TButton
    Left = 24
    Top = 70
    Width = 251
    Height = 139
    Caption = 'btn'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = btnClick
  end
end
```

Comment: Add the text to a `TStringList` and assign the `TComboBox` like: `cb.Items := TheStringList;`

Comment: I think one of the reasons may be the fact that Delphi 6 is not using the same version of ComCtl32.dll due to runtime themes?

Comment: @delphicoder it's a question of runtime performance

Comment: @LURD I've already tried using your good solution, it reduces loading times but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Delphi 6 uses `AnsiString` for everything, Delphi 10 uses `UnicodeString` instead. So there is more memory involved to move around, which could easily account for the slower performance. Also, using `TDateTime` is a poor choice for timing code.  Use `GetTickCount/64()` or better `QueryPerformanceCounter()`/`QueryPerformanceFrequency()` instead (Delphi 10 has [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) for this very purpose). Better, use an external profiler instead, like AQTime.

Comment: You may be chasing the wrong slowdown. With 4 seconds to load the same listbox 100 times with 1000 items - certainly then loading dozens of items in 10-20 combos/listboxes won't take much time. If building your UI is slow the cause is likely elsewhere.